# FusionCharts vs GoogleCharts vs HighCharts suggestions required for commercial use

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts, google-visualization, gis

I find that FusionCharts v3 evaluation and HighCharts cannot be used for commercial purpose. Google charts is the best option but those are not as good looking as any of the above. They don't even have 3d charts although their visualization API does support 3D which i cannot find. 
Is there any open source graphing or charting solution available which can be used in commercial products? 
I even looked in to [Open Flash Charts 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) but found that the developer had left the project long time a go and the currently out libs are way too buggy. I had to fix more than 50 bugs to get their 1 chart working. I tried to fix others but couldn't get Pie charts etc. working.

What i'm looking for is -
1. [Attractive](http://www.fusioncharts.com/Demos/Blueprint/) 3d column chart.
2. 3d Pie Chart.
3. [Spline](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols) Chart.
4. [Geographical](http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/GalleryMap.asp?mapName=World+Map+with+countries) Chart.

Does anyone knows any open source or free solution which can be used for commercial products?
Cheers!

Comment: "HighCharts cannot be used for commercial purpose" -- why?

Comment: You are not referring to the Highcharts.com watermark, are you? It can be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out the [FusionCharts Free Edition](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/); though it does not come with the maps. It has all the 3D column, pie and spline charts. You get the source code too!

Disclosure: I'm the Technology Evangelist & Community Manager here at FusionCharts.

Comment: FusionCharts doesn't have 3d pie charts. Also the free version looks are way too simple as compared to v3. I might go for ZingChart although it has watermark/bookmark at bottom right corner of swf. But they do have stunning looks for charts i'm looking for closer to FusionCharts v3. Ofcourse FC v3 is the winner but i might go for : http://www.zingchart.com/learn/docs.php Cheers!